# Angular *ngFor 3 nested levels page/column/row, converting javaScript to Typescript does not recognize rows.cols

Tags: angular, typescript

Attempting to convert angujarJS components to TypeScript.  The first two levels work fine, but the line

Col: {{col.id}} does not compile rows.cols, says undefined variable.  I even put rows.cols[0].id on rows repeat just to see it and it displays...  but that third level, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have created the following interfaces:

```
export interface DynamicFormCols {
  id: number;
}

export interface DynamicFormRows {
  row: number;
  cols: DynamicFormCols[];
}

export interface DynamicFormPages {
  page: number;
  pageName: string;
  rows: DynamicFormRows[];
}
```

Then defined my DymamicFormPages:

```
formPages: DynamicFormPages[] = [
    {
      page: 0, pageName: 'page1',
      rows: [
        {
          row: 0,
          cols: [
            {id: 11},
            {id: 21},
            {id: 31},
            {id: 41},
          ]
        },
        {
          row: 1,
          cols: [
            {id: 1},
            {id: 2},
            {id: 3},
            {id: 4},
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      page: 1, pageName: 'page2',
      rows: [
        {
          row: 0,
          cols: [
            {id: 1},
            {id: 2},
            {id: 3},
            {id: 4},
          ],
        },
      ]
    },
  ];
```

Then *ngFor:

```
<li *ngFor="let pages of formPages">
        <span>Page: {{pages.page}}</span>, Name: {{pages.pageName}}
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let rows of pages.rows">Row: {{rows.row}}-{{rows.cols[0].id}}{{rows.cols[1].id}}{{rows.cols[2].id}}{{rows.cols[3].id}}</li>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let col of rows.cols ">Col: {{col.id}}</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must move last ul (col ul)inside rows li.

```
    <li *ngFor="let rows of pages.rows">
      Row: {{rows.row}}
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let col of rows.cols ">Col: {{col.id}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the nesting of your list tags. Your ngFor variable "rows" only exists within the `<li>` tag that you close on the same line, so it doesn't exist in the following `<ul>` tag where you try to refer to it.

The below works by simply closing the `<li>` tag later, but you haven't stated your expected output so I can't be sure if it is what you intend.

```
<li *ngFor="let pages of formPages">
        <span>Page: {{pages.page}}</span>, Name: {{pages.pageName}}
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let rows of pages.rows">Row: {{rows.row}}-{{rows.cols[0].id}}{{rows.cols[1].id}}{{rows.cols[2].id}}{{rows.cols[3].id}}
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let col of rows.cols ">Col: {{col.id}}</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

For good semantics, you should also change "let **rows** of page.rows" to "let **row** of page.rows" because you are only dealing with 1 row at a time. (Exactly as you have done for "let col of...".)

Comment: Thank you, this conversion to TypeAScript is killin' me